Brand new FPGA burnt?
So, when I plugged in my FPGA for the first time, it started to smell a bit like chemicals, and this showed up. Is it burnt, or is it just some type of residue that popped up once I connected it?


that residue was probably there from manufacturing

I'm not an expert, but don't think this is a normal thing to happen. has this happen again or just the first time?

Just looks like flux residue

there's nothing bad here.

The marks you show just appear to be flux residues. This is a common sight on PCBs, particularly around through-hole parts which will have been hand soldered later in the assembly process.
A faint chemical smell is also not entirely unexpected the first time something is turned on. There may be flux residues on and around many of the components, so anything like power regulators that tend to run hot will initially have a faint smell as they cook off some of these residues.
If something had properly burnt up (i.e. the classic blue smoke), you would typically get a very strong and instantly recognisable burnt plastic smell.
The simplest way to find out for sure, is to try using the board and see if it functions as expected. If all appears working, I wouldn't give it much further thought.
